# After Terraform creates cluster, how do you new Kubernetes credentials with helm provider?

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm

I'm using Terraform to create a Kubernetes cluster.  As part of that, I am updating the local .kube/config with the new credentials.  Unfortunately, it looks like the Helm provider in Terraform loads its credentials at the start of the apply.  Is there a way to force the provider to load its credentials after cluster creation?

Answer (score 0):

In terraform 0.13 you can set "depends_on" on modules.

Best way to achieve what you are looking for is to separate the cluster creation and the helm into separate modules. After that put "depends_on" the cluster module on the helm module.